# Turn textboxes and buttons visible when the number of tracks it's selected in a combobox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to turn textboxes and buttons visible when the number of tracks it's selected in a combobox.

For example: when I select 3, just 3 textboxes and the 3 respective buttons to select the tracks are enabled. How can I change this code that I've made to a simple `foreach` or a `for`?

```
if (numero_faixas == 1) {
  txtFaixa1.Visible = true;
  btnFaixa1.Visible = true;
} else if (numero_faixas == 2) {
  txtFaixa1.Visible = true;
  btnFaixa1.Visible = true;
  txtFaixa2.Visible = true;
  btnFaixa2.Visible = true;
} else if (numero_faixas == 3) {
  txtFaixa1.Visible = true;
  btnFaixa1.Visible = true;
  txtFaixa2.Visible = true;
  btnFaixa2.Visible = true;
  txtFaixa3.Visible = true;
  btnFaixa3.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Try doing a google search on `Controls` class and how to loop thru Controls  also watch your foul language on this site please...!

Comment: Ayy lmao DAT CODE!! And if you will have like 10 more text fields and buttons, you will write 1000 more lines?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a proof of concept that you could respin using your business rules.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShowHideButtons_47439046
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitOurThings();
        }

        private void InitOurThings()
        {
            //lets create a combo box with options to select
            ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
            combo.Location = new Point(5, 5);//place it somewhere

            //add selectable items
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                combo.Items.Add(i);
            }

            combo.SelectedValueChanged += Combo_SelectedValueChanged;//the event which will handle the showing/hidding
            Controls.Add(combo);//add the combo box to the form


            //lets create some buttons and textboxes
            int btnx = 5;
            int btny = combo.Height + combo.Location.Y + 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Location = new Point(btnx, btny);
                btn.Name = i.ToString();
                btn.Text = i.ToString();
                Controls.Add(btn);
                btny += btn.Height + 5;

                TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
                txtbx.Location = new Point(btn.Location.X + btn.Width + 5, btn.Location.Y);
                txtbx.Name = i.ToString();
                txtbx.Text = i.ToString();
                Controls.Add(txtbx);
            }

        }

        private void Combo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int selectedValue = int.Parse(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString());

            foreach (Control item in Controls)
            {
                //show/hide the controls based on their Name being Equal Or Smaller than the selectedItem
                if (item is TextBox)
                {
                    int itemNumber = int.Parse(item.Name);
                    item.Visible = itemNumber <= selectedValue ? true : false;
                }
                if (item is Button)
                {
                    int itemNumber = int.Parse(item.Name);
                    item.Visible = itemNumber <= selectedValue ? true : false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: way too much code, this can be done in a more efficient way  IMO

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce the lines of code by changing your conditions, so you don't have to reference the same control so many times:

```
if (numero_faixas > 0)
{
    txtFaixa1.Visible = true;
    btnFaixa1.Visible = true;
}
if (numero_faixas > 1)
{
    txtFaixa2.Visible = true;
    btnFaixa2.Visible = true;
}
if (numero_faixas > 2)
{
    txtFaixa3.Visible = true;
    btnFaixa3.Visible = true;
}
```

To use a `foreach` loop, you could cast the `Controls` collection to an `IEnumerable<Control>` and then, `using System.Linq;`, you can filter on controls of type `TextBox` and `Button`, where the control name contains `"Faxia"`. Then, in the loop body, we can use `int.TryParse` to try to convert the last character of the control name to an int, and if that succeeds, then set the control to `Visible` if the control number is less than `numero_faixas + 1`:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls.Cast<Control>()
    .Where(c => (c is Button || c is TextBox) && c.Name.Contains("Faixa")))
{
    // Get the number associated with this control and compare it to numero_faixas
    int controlNumber;
    if (int.TryParse(control.Name.Substring(control.Name.Length - 1), out controlNumber) &&
        controlNumber < numero_faixas + 1)
    {
        control.Visible = true;
    }
}
```